# Measuring spectral tilt

Tags: frequency-spectrum, gradient

I have quite a few noisy signals and I want to calculate their spectral tilt over time, preferably using a method from literature. So far, I can only come up with the slope of the line between the F0 and F1 peaks. The problem is, I don't know how to calculate the spectral tilt by hand for the below example (which is a cross-cut of the energy-frequency spectrum), because F1 is so low.

[image: I am not using a spectrogram here, but a cochleogram, but it should work the same.]

The frequencies and energies of all the peaks are the following:

```
 Freq (Hz) Energy (dB)
    95.465 -46.700
   142.06  -43.072
   178.24  -43.564
   269.82  -14.422
   405.93  -34.140
   537.26  -19.539
   803.47  - 2.081
  1060.3   -10.409
  1315.0   -14.574
  1581.0   -24.363
  1843.0   -29.801
  2214.9   -34.464
  2744.3   -28.979
  3197.9   -26.913
  3961.1   -30.493
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: i dunno how the lit defines *"spectral tilt"* but if there is an agreement regarding how amplitude and frequency are scaled, i imagine it's the slope of some sorta weighted least-square fit for a straight line.  if you decide that it's log-amplitude vs. log-frequency and you specify a frequency range for the data, you can compute a value in dB per octave or dB per decade.  do you know how to do least-squares fit to data?

Comment: You're right. I should first wonder what spectral tilt actually _is_. I'll come back if I have that clear.